# Android. Кастомный лист ListView(текст+изображение). Как вывести сначала текст потом изображение

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter, imageview

Создал свой адаптер на основе BaseAdapter. В моем ListView есть TextView и ImageView. Картинки я подгружаю из сети(в AsyncTask). Все здорово на мой лист очень большой и картинок сотни...поэтому весь мой лист выводится только когда подгрузятся все картинки.. А я хочу сначала вывести текст (он быстро подргружается), а затем по мере загрузки картинок добавлять их по одной в мой ListView. Это вообще возможно реализовать? Допустим изначально я задам вместо картинок значение null, но как мне потом обновлять лист и добавлять картинки? Может кто еще какие-нибудь несложные реализации подскажет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай свой объект пихай в него url к картинки

```
class Model {
    private String url;
    private String text;


 /*getter and setter*/
}
```

Формируй список моделей List listModels = ....
передавай в адаптер и там уже картинки через Piccaso подгружай асинхронно и будет все хорошо работать картинки будут кешироваться

Comment: Вот, это то, как раз что мне было нужно. Никак не мог догадаться, что подгрузку надо делать в самом адапторе. Спасибо огромное, заработало!

Answer (score 4):

Если не возбраняется, то я бы посоветовал вам использовать библиотеку `Piccaso` для подгрузки фотографий. 
На [оф. странице](http://square.github.io/picasso/) есть достаточно подробный how-to
Таким образом вам не придется писать велосипед и вы убережете себя от кастомной, вероятно с багами, реализации.

Comment: Чем загружать изображение это уже второй вопрос, на данный момент у меня быстро выводится ListView, в котором TextView уже заполнен, а вот ImageView еще пустой (null), вопрос в том, могу ли я теперь пройтись отдельно по ImageView (по каждому item) и заполнить его картинками ... (неважно как я их загружаю, но к примеру с помощью Piccaso через AsynkTask)

Comment: Picasso мне даст возможно быстро загрузить картинку по URL и добавить по id в ImageView, а как мне пройтись по imageview каждого элемента списка и добавить изображения постепенно во все item

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) он может подгружать картинки сразу в нескольких потоках. И пока картинки грузятся устанавливает картинки заглушки.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно организовать добавление данных в адаптер через AsynkTask, а для загрузки изображений используйте picasso или UIL.