# Как подгружать картинки в фоновом режиме в уже созданный ListView

Tags: android

Имеется приложение получающее текст и картинки `base64` в формате `json` из внешней БД.

Если подгружать все объекты из БД - грузится долго. Поэтому, хочу подгрузить сначала текст, а картинки из БД должны тянуться в фоновом режиме, то есть `ListView` с текстом и пустым местом под картинки уже сформирован. Делаю через `AsynchTask`. Не могу сообразить как мне реализовать фоновую подгрузку только картинок.

Видел точно такой же вопрос [Android. Кастомный лист ListView(текст+изображение). Как вывести сначала текст потом изображение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512820/android-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-listview%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF?answertab=active#tab-top), но там ответ не совсем развернутый, я не совсем его вкурил, а поучаствовать в обсуждении не дает ибо нуб :)

Буду признателен за пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подгружайте картинки в отдельном потоке, обновляйте данные в вашем адаптере и делайте `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, у меня сейчас  в onPostExecute так:         
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.item, new String[]{"brand","price","model", "img"},new int[] {R.id.textView6, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5, R.id.imageView1});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            if (pBar.isShown())
                pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);} То есть мне нужно сделать отдельный АТ и вызвать его из этого onPostExecute?

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо